# C# parametric delegate creation for ListView grouping

Tags: c#, listview

I have a groupable listview with many columns and I want every column to group according to ranges defined by an array.

Currently I have to write:

```
_priceColumn.GroupItemAccessor = new ColumnItemValueAccessor(GetPriceGroupValueFromItem)

Decimal[] mSplitters = { 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000, 10000000000 };
private Object GetPriceGroupValueFromItem(Object o)
{
    decimal? price = ((Ticker)o).Price;


    if (price == null)
    {
        return "Null";
    }

    int cnt = mSplitters.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
    {
        if (i == cnt - 1 && (price > mSplitters[i]))
            return $"Price > ({mSplitters[i].ShortFormat()})"; 
        if (price < mSplitters[i])
        {
            if (i > 0)
                return $"Price ({mSplitters[i - 1].ShortFormat()} - {mSplitters[i].ShortFormat()})";
            else
                return $"Price < ({mSplitters[i].ShortFormat()})";
        }
    }
    return "Error";
}
```

Thats a lot of code to copy and adjust for every colum.

What I want is something like:

```
_priceColumn.GroupItemAccessor = 
new ColumnItemValueAccessor(Helpers.CreateGroupValueDelegate(Ticker.Price, mSplittersToGroupBy, "Price", FormatExtensionMethodToUse))
```

I would need to pass "Price" and FormatExtensionMethodToUse for it to create the correct strings for or columns like "Price", "24h High", "Change"

In case it helps, The ListView I'm using here is this one https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20052/Outlook-Style-Grouped-List-Control

I hope anyone can help be and stop the messy copy and pasting.

The question is related to another question about a delegate for comparing methodes that I decided to post separately to avoid making a messy first post.

Btw: If anyone knows a better free (preferably wpf) listview that supports nested groups and easy drag and drop grouping by draging column headers please let me know.